# Change color of caption text in toctree

Tags: html, css, python-sphinx, caption, toctree

Is there a way to change the color of captions on a sphinx webpage? I'm using the `:caption:` directive with *toctree*, but the caption comes out almost the same color as the sidebar. For reference [here](http://syntaf.github.io/vocal/) is the link to the page with the hard to see captions and here is my index file:

```
Contents
============

.. toctree::
   :caption: User Documentation
   :maxdepth: 2

   overview
   installation
   tutorial

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Developer Documentation

   dev/conventions
   dev/enviroment
   dev/docs
   dev/site
   doc/modules

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Support

   trouble/faq
   trouble/issuetracker
   trouble/contact
```

Comment: Hello, did you manage to do this? I need exactly the same thing and none of the answers provided below are working for me... ( I am using the sphinx_rtd_theme, by the way)

Answer (score 2):

You could add a color attribut to span.caption-text? For example in your `source/_static/custom.css`put:

```
@import url("default.css");
span.caption-text {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: This changes not only the color on the sidebar, but also on the `toctree` directive caption... What is the solution for changing the side bar color only?

Answer (score 1):

@aflp91 will indeed change caption text in the side bar, but also the caption text in the `toctree` as well.

If you want the caption color to change in side bar - and side bar only - you should add this

```css
.wy-menu > .caption > span.caption-text {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```